# Is Thread.sleep(x) accurate enough to use as a clock in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a separate thread running in my main class. It needs to send a message every 100 milliseconds, but EXACTLY every 100ms. I am wondering if it is accurate enough to be used as such, or if there is an alternative to have something happen exactly 10 times a second.

```
class ClockRun implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        double hourlyRate = Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString("hourlyRate", ""));
        double elapsedTime = 0;
        do {
            while(clockRun){
                double amount = hourlyRate / 360 /100 * elapsedTime;
                elapsedTime++;
                Bundle clockData = new Bundle();
                clockData.putString("value", String.format("$%.2f", amount));

                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.setData(clockData);


                handler.sendMessage(message);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }while (mainRun);

        Notify.viaToast(getApplication(), "Thread stopped.");

    }
}
```

Comment: Even if sleep were accurate, this code wouldn't send a message every 100ms, it would send it every (100 + time to run non-sleep code) ms. Also, "exactly every 100ms" isn't the same as "exactly 10 times a second": the latter requirement can be satisfied by doing it 10 times, then sleeping for the rest of the second.

Comment: Android is not a real-time OS. There is no means by which you can ensure that you do anything "exactly every 100ms", as the CPU may be off doing other things at that exact moment in time.

Comment: so how does a stopwatch work in android...? @CommonsWare

Comment: If I were to write a stopwatch app, I would use `postDelayed()` to arrange to get control on the main application thread periodically (e.g., every 100ms). But then I would update the stopwatch UI to reflect **how much time has actually elapsed** (e.g., the difference between `SystemClock.currentTimeMillis()` when the stopwatch started and the `SystemClock.currentTimeMillis()` value right now), rather than assume that I get control *precisely* every 100ms. This is a well-understood problem, as timing programs have been around for 30+ years.

Comment: My application has a stopwatch function, can I do the same on the side thread somehow? Maybe get the total amount of time elapsed and multiply it by the amount variable, and send that in the bundle.

Comment: @CommonsWare, There is _no_ operating system that can ensure that you do anything exactly every 100ms.  Some are better than others, but none is perfect.  The phrase "real-time" implies that there are timing requirements, but it does not imply any particular precision in the timing.  If your requirements are loose enough, you can write real-time software for _any_ platform (Don't ask me how I know.)

Comment: @jameslarge: Yes, but in the spectrum of possibilities, Android is rather far on the side of not-real-time (unreal-time? fake-time? whatever).

Comment: @shmag18, the biggest problem with your example is that `sleep()` is inaccurate, and if you depend on summing sleep() times for your timekeeping, then you will also be summing the errors.  The longer your clock runs, the farther off it might be.   A much better strategy is to ask the operating system for an accurate time check (e.g., `System.currentTimeMillis()`) each time around the loop, and then compute how long to sleep for your next interval.   You'll still be off by _one_ sleep() error, but you won't be adding up the errors.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Fair Enough!

Comment: Thanks guys, very helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it is not accurate at all,

From the docs:

***(temporarily cease
      execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers.***
In other words, this sleep is OS or environment dependant, you can't predict the OS scheduling decision, plus, the sleep can be terminated by an interrupt.

Again from the docs:

[In any case, you cannot assume that invoking sleep will suspend the thread for precisely the time period specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Moreover, it is not efficient because you will be wasting CPU cycles just for sleeping.

[ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) will provide a better precision and performance.
Simply wrap your task in Callable or Runnable and use `ScheduledExecutorService` to execute them, there are plenty of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method, because it fires every given time, no matter how long it takes for the code in `run()` method to complete.

I think it would be something like this:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            // Do your stuff      
    }
});

ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```